# UpdateSite build error in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I just finished to code an Eclipse plugin, I created a feature for this plugin, and an update site for this feature. Nothing special for the moment, I just followed step by step the instructions.
But when I click on "build" in the site.xml file, I have a dialog box telling me that there is problem :

---

Problem occured

'Build site' has encountered a problem.
An internal error occured during : "Build site".

An internal error occurred during: "Build Site".
while trying to invoke the method java.lang.Object.equals(java.lang.Object) of a null object loaded from local variable 'osAlias'

---

I searched some similar cases online, but didn't find anything about this "osAlias" local variable.

Any help would be appreciated Smile

Thanks for reading.

EDIT : The same problem occurs when I try to export a feature. The error message is the same, but with "Export feature" instead of "Build Site"

Comment: Could you provide your feature.xml?

Comment: Hi Peter, thanks for your answer. I just solved my problem by downloading the latest Eclipse version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution : the error occurred because of the Eclipse version. I downloaded Eclipse Mars 2 and everything works fine.